# User prompt Filter in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter my dataset by taking the two range values from the user. I am using these two values in two variable 't1' & 't2'. Later on, I am using these variables to filter my dataset. But the problem is with these user prompted values, my filter is not working. The filtering works fine with fixed values but doesn't work with variable values. Providing the code for convenience:

```
`Sub GetUserInput()

Dim t1 As Long, t2 As Long
t1 = InputBox("Type the upper torque limit")
t2= InputBox("Type the lower torque limit")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Below Code segment will find out the Time, Input Torque & Output speed    columns from the raw data set regardless of their position

Sheets(3).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Sheets(2).Activate
Columns("A").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(3).Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial
ActiveCell.Select
Sheets(2).Activate

'Find "D2TQSH" in Row 1
With Sheets(2).Rows(1)
Set t = .Find("D2TQSH", lookat:=xlPart)
'If found, copy the column to Sheet 2, Column A
'If not found, present a message
If Not t Is Nothing Then
Columns(t.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
Destination:=Sheets(3).Range("B1")
Else: MsgBox "D2TQSH Not Found"
End If
End With

'Find "D2SPDFR" in Row 1
With Sheets(2).Rows(1)
Set t = .Find("D2SPDFR", lookat:=xlPart)
'If found, copy the column to Sheet 2, Column A
'If not found, present a message
 If Not t Is Nothing Then
 Columns(t.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
 Destination:=Sheets(3).Range("C1")
 Else: MsgBox "D2SPDFR Not Found"
 End If
 End With

'Below code segment will filter out data based on the user input values

Sheets(3).Activate

With Sheet3
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter
.Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=-t1", _
Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=-t2"
End With

'Copy the filtered data.
Range("A1:C1", ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

'Paste filtered dataset to the Output Sheet
Sheets(4).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Sheets(3).AutoFilterMode = False
`
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it won't work, you are filtering your columns for values "t1" and "t2", note - they are string, text values!
You should use

```
.Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & CStr(-t1), _
 Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CStr(-t2)
```

This will combine string ">=" with value of your t1 and t2 variables, converted to string.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it yesterday. But I used below syntax n it worked fine:

.Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">= -" & t1 _
 Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<= -" & t2

Comment: @Imtiaz This results in same strings as my version, and I always try to do explicit type converisons.